# Can anyone help me make a 3d plot from these variables?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am a kind of newbie in using Matlab and I have a problem of producing a 3d plot using these three variables.

The variables are:

```
P=[1 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.2];
N=[0.1429 0.2857 0.4286 0.5714 0.7143 0.8571 1.0000];
K =
    0.0359    0.0340    0.0315    0.0298    0.0309
    0.0700    0.0669    0.0618    0.0602    0.0601
    0.1018    0.0961    0.0896    0.0866    0.0897
    0.1270    0.1192    0.1152    0.1091    0.1127
    0.1444    0.1390    0.1322    0.1235    0.1284
    0.1556    0.1509    0.1424    0.1375    0.1419
    0.1656    0.1598    0.1536    0.1466    0.1500
```

In Matlab, `K` is in the form of `K(:,1),(K:2),k(:,3),K(:,4) and K(:,5)`

can anyone help me please on how to do it?.

I have copied some sections of the code below:

```
P=[1 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.2];

LAMBDA = linspace(0,1,8) * c;

for iL = 1:length(LAMBDA)

    lambda = LAMBDA(iL);
    for iP=1:length(P)
        [Pbi,Pbo,Pb,Rhoi,Rhoo,Rho]=Sim_traffic(lambdai(iL),lambdao(iL),mu,ci,co,1-epsi);
        P_out_p(iL,iP) = (lambdai(iL).*(1-P_B_i_conv_s(iL)).*inner_outage(iL,iPR) + lambdao(iL).*(1-P_B_o_conv_s(iL)).*out_outage(iL,iPR));
    end
end

N=LAMBDA./c;

K=P_out_p(:,:);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking to use `surf` and will need `meshgrid` as well:

```
[p,n] = meshgrid(P,N)dimensions are wrong...
surf(p,n,K)
```

Although looking at [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html), I think you might be able to skip the `meshgrid` line here:

```
surf(P,N,K)
```

Comment: [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) can do the `meshgrid` for you internally, you can call it using the original vectors `surf( N, P, K );`

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I tried to do what you proposed here but I get an error that "Data dimensions must agree".Please more help

Comment: @JenasWilliams sorry I swapped the axes by accident. Try the lastest edit (i.e. swap all you `P`s and `N`s)

Comment: `surf(P,N,K)`. Look at my answer again, I have edited it to work now

Comment: still didn't make it, please have a look at this and help me, I have copied some sections of the code

Comment: @JenasWilliams That is unreadable. Please just edit your question and add the code there nicely formatted

Comment: I have edited it and added to the main post to make it readable

Comment: Just make sure your dimensions match. Your code is not really of use to anyone as it contains external variables and functions. Make sure that `numel(P)==size(K,2)` and that `numel(N)==size(K,1)`